# How do you sort each character in a .txt file?

Tags: python

For example, if a .txt file consists:
*car
and
day*

I want to make them in alphabet order:
*acr
adn
ady*

Here's what I have in my code right now:

```
def read_file(fileName):
    list = []
    with open(fileName) as f:
         list = f.read().split()
         list.sort()
    return list
```

It just won't sort the way I want, do I need a nested for loop?

Comment: Side-note: Don't name variables with the same name as built-ins; it shadows the name, denying you (in this case) access to the `list` constructor, which can be very confusing.

Comment: Thank you, I'll remember this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need this:

```
def read_file(fileName):
    with open(fileName) as f:
        a_list = f.read().split()
        result = ' '.join([''.join(sorted(a)) for a in a_list])
    return result
```

Comment: You were faster!

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort the letters of each word, not the words themselves:

```
string = "car and day"
" ".join(["".join(sorted(word)) for word in string.split()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of list.sort():

```
# don't use `list` as variable
lyst = f.read().split()
" ".join(["".join(sorted(list(i))) for i in lyst])
```